# Associated primes and their heights

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $(S,m)$ be a commutative Gorenstein local ring, $I$ an ideal of $S$ such that $\operatorname{ht} I=t$, and $R=S/I$. Let $a \in m$ be an $R$-regular element such that for any prime ideal $p\in\operatorname{Ass}_{S}(R)$, $\operatorname{ht}p=t$. Then, for any prime ideal $p \in \operatorname{Ass}_{S}(R/aR)$, $\operatorname{ht}p=t+1$?

Comment: On the line line, you probably wanted to say ht$p = t + 1$. This is more or less a duplication of the question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/724772/84157. The answer I wrote shows that it is not true.

Comment: In your counter example, R is Gorenstein?

Comment: @user138400: No. It is not Cohen-Macaulay. If it were what you are asking is true even for regular sequences.

Comment: All these questions about height unmixed ideals are solved by a (counter)example given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/206185/121097).